# String.Join - different behavior for the parameter and direct value

Tags: c#, .net

I run code bellow, result1 is equal "" but string.Join(",", null) throw an exception

```
string str = null;
var result1 = string.Join(",", str);
var result2 = string.Join(",", null);
```

Also it doesn't work for this code(throw an exception)

```
.ForMember(dst => dst.Ids, opt => opt.MapFrom(string.Join(",", src.Ids)))
```

But works for this:

```
.ForMember(dst => dst.Ids, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Ids == null ? null : string.Join(",", src.Ids)))
```

How explain this behaviour?

Comment: Second `Join` call is not the same function that is called. `null` by itself has no type.

Comment: @John both calls the same method

Comment: @TanveerBadar I've added one more example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both use the same overload of [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Join_System_String_System_String___) - which is the one that takes in a string as a separator and `string[]` as a value.
More accurately - `params string[] value` - and that is the key point of the observed difference behavior.

The first line of code - `string.Join(",", str);` where `str` is a null reference of a string, actually gets resolved as `string.Join("," new string[] {null})`.

The second line, however, gets resolved as `string.Join("," null)`. - meaning the string array itself is null and therefor the exception is thrown.

**update**
You get different results with automapper because the result of the following code

```
string str = null;
var result1 = string.Join(",", str);
```

is not null, it's an empty string.

Comment: @BasilKosovan, nothing with auto mapper, pls see my answer

Comment: I have an exception, not [null] and [string empty] @ZoharPeled

Comment: I assume `src.Ids` is an array, so it works like `var result2 = string.Join(",", null);`

Comment: @BasilKosovan "I have an exception" -> What exception do you get? Anyway, it seems to be a different question than what you started with

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd parameter for join takes in `params string[] value`. In your first case you are sending in an array of strings with 1 value (null). For the 2nd case you are sending in null as the string array.

Answer (score 2):

**First Try**

```
string str = null;
var result1 = string.Join(",", str);
```

The code above transalted into

```
string text = null;
string[] obj = new string[1];
string text2 = string.Join(",", obj);
```

**Second Try**

And last line of code;

```
var result2 = string.Join(",", null);
```

translated into;

```
string.Join(",", (string[])null);
```

You can see yourself at
https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCU+hxTjTRUcADOgM4AuATugC86AHYBXADaSA3MgBuAQ0H8Aptym84wzJwB0AKQD2AS1HUARABprPAbTlIlK9Zpg72HQ6fPXbE6QcWdABfZBCgA==

P.S: sharplab is love =)

Comment: Thank you and +1 for proving my answer :-)

Comment: Ikr, ur answer actually right, but sometimes people need to see it with their own eyes =)